# Why is "strategies to cutting" correct in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I'm reading *When Breath Becomes Air* by the late Paul Kalanithi, and I came across the sentence:

> I could see that there were two strategies to cutting the time short...

My question is why *to cutting* is used rather than *for cutting*.

Comment: Either could be used.

Comment: Because you can use either there.

Comment: Both "for cutting" and "to cut" sound better to me than "to cutting".

Comment: To me, _to cutting_ sounds as if the writer couldn't decide whether he wanted to say _to cut_ or _for cutting_, and ended up merging them into something which, as far as I'm concerned, is not idiomatic.

Comment: Ask the author. Either is correct and there is no difference in meaning. Different people will often think there must be, and use them in different contexts (whatever they can come up with), but all these individual distinctions are arbitrary and random, so they cancel out.

Comment: To=goal, for=purpose. It's fairly marginal.

Comment: Note that _strategies to cutting_ is not a constituent. _Cutting the time short_ is a verb phrase, in this case a gerund clause as the object of _to_. _Strategies_ simply means _ways_ here, so it's _there are 3 ways for cutting it short_.

Answer (score 2):

It's incorrect. [As Ngram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strategies+to+getting%2Cstrategies+for+getting&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), "strategies for getting" (as an example) is very common, while "strategies to getting" is nearly nonexistent. That said, "strategies to get" is [indeed valid.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strategies+to+getting%2Cstrategies+for+getting%2Cstrategies+to+get&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

I suspect that the author confused "strategies to cut" with "strategies for cutting," leading to the erroneous "strategies to cutting."

Answer (score 1):

To/for cutting [the time short] is a dative complement of strategy. It acts adjectivally. The to/for in this context are more grammatical case markers than prepositions, thus they result in the same meaning:

there were two strategies to [i.e. that contribute towards] cutting the time short. (beneficial dative)

there were two strategies for *the purpose of* cutting the time short (dative of purpose.)

(You should have given more context, as it is possible that omitting to/for would still be grammatical.)

Answer (score 0):

As much as I know, "cutting" here acts like a noun and it is common to use. That is a bit different from Gerund and Infintive structure, but "to" is a preposition + gerund (verb+ing) here. And I assume that you are native of a language which "to" and "for" are used interchangeably in it.